# Is this site getting a custom layout?

Tags: feature-request

This is the first time I've participated in a StackExchange site that's made it out of beta. I've seen other sites have a custom layout and I think I heard in the StackOverflow podcast that some sites get custom layouts.

Is this site getting one just for making it out of beta or is it only popular sites that have this privilege?

Comment: It's my understanding that they will, but perhaps someone from Stack can respond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Feedback Requested: Design-Independent Graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation)

> #### The Community Team announces that a site is cleared for graduation. Without delay...
>
> - the beta label is removed
> - elections are held
> - migration paths are set up
> - community ads are run
> - a link to the site is added to the footer
>
> #### ...Then, as it becomes available
>
> - the site gets their custom design.
> - privilege thresholds are increased to graduated site levels

The key to the answer is "as it becomes available". I remember reading in another thread that the SE designers have a bunch of custom designs in their queue, so Magento SE will get one eventually.

Comment: I can only imagine the amount of work required to make and maintain custom layouts for every site. I can picture somone in that team saying _"What were we thinking?!"_

Comment: They say they're hiring designers as fast as they can on-board them, but I also imagine there would be a critical mass point where all the design work would be eaten up in a month and then everyone would get laid-off. I imagine they're attempting to get it all done, but also be sustainable.

Answer (score 1):

The info in [fschmengler's answer](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/667/3052) is the most current available at the moment. Just to confirm, we do *intend* to give all graduated sites custom designs, but unfortunately, it could take quite some time (several months at least) before your design actually arrives. Generally a designer drops by meta to share a first draft shortly before anything goes live.